# Three dot ∴ symbol meaning

Tags: notation

Whats the meaning of this symbol?
Its a three dot symbol: ∴
I read a book, im could not find any definition of this symbol.

This is about continuum property of the natural numbers and the archimedean property:

for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$,

$n>B-1$

∴ $n+1>B$

this should be a proof on the set $\mathbb{N}$ of natural numbers is unbounden above. But I do not understand it.

An answer on how the three-dot symbol is what I am out after. Additional explanation of the proof would be nice to know as well, but not needed.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Therefore_sign

Comment: " im could not find any definition of this symbol." I simply Googled "∴ symbol" and it told me the same thing as the accepted answer. I don't see why this question was asked as it was only asked recently in 2019, and I don't think Google lacked this result back then.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The symbol $\therefore$ means “therefore”.

Answer (score 8):

The three dot symbol $\therefore$ means therefore.

Less common,  $\;\because$ means because.

Assume $n > B-1$.  By a well-known property of $>$ (add $1$ to both sides), $\;\therefore n+1>B.$

For any potential upper bound $B$ of $\mathbb N,$ by the Archimedean property there is $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $n \ge B > B-1.$  But then $n+1\in \mathbb N $ and $n+1>B,$ so $B$ is not really an upper bound of $\mathbb N$.  This contradiction shows there is not an upper bound $B$ of $\mathbb N.$

Answer (score 0):

This triple dot symbol $\therefore$ is denoted "thus" or "therefore".

Comment: I don't see how this answer adds anything of value compared to the already existing ones.